# <option> value should equal var and pull in var as html

Tags: javascript, jquery, var

Im trying to take the selected  value and .on('change') populate another option with the option list in the var

html

```
<div class="filterContainer populated ms-Grid-col ms-u-sm8 ms-u-smPush2">
                                <div class="ms-Toggle">

                                     <label class="ms-Toggle-field dimension" for="demo-toggle-3">
                                        <span class="ms-Label displayInline ms-Label--off ms-and">AND</span>
                                        <span class="ms-Label displayInline ms-Label--on ms-or">OR</span>
                                     </label>
                                </div>
enter code here

                                <div class="ms-Grid-col ms-u-sm9 ms-u-md9 ms-u-lg9  bgYellow">
                                    <div tabindex="0" class="ms-Dropdown">
                                        <i class="ms-Dropdown-caretDown ms-Icon ms-Icon--caretDown"></i>
enter code here
```

> This selected option value should change/populate the last select options

```
                                        <select class="ms-Dropdown-select dimensionSelection" id="queryType">
                                            <option value="source" data-filter-top="source">source</option>
                                            <option value="departments" data-filter-top="department">department</option>
                                            <option value="funct" data-filter-top="function">function</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div tabindex="0" class="ms-Dropdown">
                                        <i class="ms-Dropdown-caretDown ms-Icon ms-Icon--caretDown"></i>

                                        <select class="ms-Dropdown-select" id="queryType">
                                            <option>Equals</option>
                                            <option>Not Equals</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div tabindex="0" class="ms-Dropdown">
                                        <i class="ms-Dropdown-caretDown ms-Icon ms-Icon--caretDown"></i>
```

This select option should be updated based on the new selection from above.

```
                                        <select class="ms-Dropdown-select selectionBase" id="queryType">
                                            <option class="">THIS OPTOIN SHOULD CHANGE</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>';
```

> Jquery
>   Here are teh variables

```
var source = '<option>Sales</option>\
                  <option>Marketing</option>\
                  <option>Dev</option>';

    var department = '<option>Sales</option>\
                      <option>Marketing</option>\
                      <option>Dev</option>';

    var func = '<option>Seattle</option>\
                      <option>Los Angeles</option>\
                      <option>San Francisco</option>\
                      <option>Bellevue</option>';

    var location = '<option>Seattle</option>\
                      <option>Los Angeles</option>\
                      <option>San Francisco</option>\
                      <option>Bellevue</option>';

    var domain = '<option>Seattle</option>\
                      <option>Los Angeles</option>\
                      <option>San Francisco</option>\
                      <option>Bellevue</option>';


    var isinternal = '<option>Yes</option>\
                      <option>No</option>';

$('div').on('change','select.dimensionSelection', function(e){
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".selectionBase").html($(this).attr('value'));
    alert("this is hapenin")
});
```

Comment: First of all, use `jQuery.val` instead of `jQuery.html` to set the `value`

Comment: So I just tried that. It does indeed update. But It just leave a blank option

Comment: Let me clarify. I need to remove the current <option>'s and add new options that are stored in variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have an object which will hold all the variables as value of the keys and keys will be mapped with the value(`markup`) of the option:

Make note of few things:

- Do not conflict with global variables and gobal properties of `window` object, in your example, variable `location` was making webpage to redirect as `window.locatoin` will redirect the webpage.
- Use `.change()` method to invoke the handler function initially.

```js
var source = '<option>Sales</option>\
                  <option>Marketing</option>\
                  <option>Dev</option>';

var department = '<option>Sales</option>\
                      <option>Marketing</option>\
                      <option>Dev</option>';

var func = '<option>Seattle</option>\
                      <option>Los Angeles</option>\
                      <option>San Francisco</option>\
                      <option>Bellevue</option>';

var locationElem = '<option>Seattle</option>\
                      <option>Los Angeles</option>\
                      <option>San Francisco</option>\
                      <option>Bellevue</option>';

var domainName = '<option>Seattle</option>\
                      <option>Los Angeles</option>\
                      <option>San Francisco</option>\
                      <option>Bellevue</option>';


var isinternal = '<option>Yes</option>\
                      <option>No</option>';
var obj = {
  source: source,
  department: department,
  func: func,
  location: locationElem,
  domain: domainName,
  isinternal: isinternal
};

$('select.dimensionSelection').on('change', function() {
  if (this.value) {
    $(".selectionBase").html(obj[this.value]);
  }
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="ms-Dropdown-select dimensionSelection" id="queryType">
  <option value="source" data-filter-top="source">source</option>
  <option value="department" data-filter-top="department">department</option>
  <option value="func" data-filter-top="function">function</option>
</select>
<div tabindex="0" class="ms-Dropdown">
  <i class="ms-Dropdown-caretDown ms-Icon ms-Icon--caretDown"></i>
</div>
<select class="ms-Dropdown-select selectionBase">
  <option class="">THIS OPTOIN SHOULD CHANGE</option>
</select>
```

Comment: So. The problem im facing is that the .filterContainer is not immediately available to the DOM. I am trying to change the option within the parent container.

Comment: @user3328590 – There were many issue, you must ttach `event-delegation` on the closest persistent element as parent, not `div` for sure...

Comment: Actually we are all good. I just need to add .change() after attr('value')
Thanks Rayon!

Answer (score 0):

A couple things.

It's a little hard to understand exactly what you're trying to do, so a bit more context can be really helpful. I'm mostly going to talk about how you can clean this up and make it a little easier to work with. Hopefully this gets some of the noise out of your way and lets you figure out where your real problem is.

First up, bugs:

- You have a typo, the first select has a value of `"funct"` but the related list of options is named `func`.
- You have two (maybe 3?) `<select>` DOM elements with the same `id="queryType"`

Since you're creating a single-functionality `<select>` it's fair to give it an id like `id="dependent"` or something like that. Using an `id` makes your code way easier to read than a bunch of chaining `.parent().parent().children('select')` type stuff. Maybe call the first one `id="primary"` or `id="driver"` or something.

This makes your code more specialized and less generic. But sometimes the time/work overhead of making things generic just isn't worth it if you don't see a need for it any time in the near future. You can always go back and generic-ify it later if you need to.

Next, every time you have a lot of stuff repeated, or you feel like (or are) copy-pasting, it should clue you in that you have an opportunity for optimizing you code and making it easier to use and update. For instance, instead of the lengthy string objects with the stringified html (also any time you're compelled to use stringified html, you should stop for a second and consider doing things differently), you can look at them and say, "Oh, these all look really similar, ho can I make this code easier to work with?"

```
var optsConfig = {
    source: ['Sales', 'Marketing', 'Dev'],
    department: 'Sales', 'Marketing', 'Dev'],
    func: ['Seattle', 'Los Angeles', 'San Francisco', 'Bellevue'],
    // ...
};
```

Then when you need to use them, instead of stringified HTML you can actually make the DOM elements themselves. I'm not up on my jQuery so I usually just do things the native way, hopefully this removes some of the obscuring shit that jQuery is putting in your way.

```
// Let's say this is the value selected by the user in the first dropdown

function appendOptionEls(selectEl, options) {
    options.forEach(function(name) {
        var el = document.createElement('option');
        el.value = name.toLowerCase();
        el.textContent = name;
        selectEl.appendChild(el);
    });
}

function onDriverChange(driverSelection) {
    var dependentOptions = optsConfig[driverSelection];

    var secondSelect = $('select#dependent');
    secondSelect.empty();

    appendOptionEls(secondSelect, dependentOptions);
}
```

Not sure if that ^ is perfect jQuery (it's been a while), but something like that will make it easier to modify your `optsConfig`, add/remove elements from it, etc. But assuming the above works, you'll end up with something like:

```
<select id="dependent">
    <option value="seattle">Seattle</option>
    <option value="los angeles">Los Angeles</option>
    <option value="san francisco">San Francisco</option>
    <option value="bellevue">Bellevue</option>
</select>
```

So after all that jibber jabber, you should be able to do something like...

```
$('#driver').on('change', function(e) {
    var driverSelection = $(this).val();
    onDriverChange(driverSelection);

    alert("this is hapenin")
});
```

There's more work to be done around making sure you don't try to do stuff with `undefined` vars or whatnot, but something like this should work.

Comment: Thanks dude. This helps a bunch.